# Efficiently find objects satisfying relationship

Tags: python, large-data

Let's say I have some objects, like in this example (JSON code):

```
{
    "people" : {
        "Alice" : {
            "position" : "Manager",
            "company" : "Company1"
        },
        "Bob" : {
            "position" : "CEO",
            "company" : "Company1"
        },
        "Charlie" : {
            "position" : "CEO",
            "company" : "Company2"
        }
    },
    "companies" : [
        { "name" : "Company1" },
        { "name" : "Company2" }
    ]
}
```

And I want to write a function `get_X_of_Y(x, y)` that I could use to pass, for example, `get_X_of_Y("CEO", companies[0])` and have it return `Bob`.

How could I efficiently do this for large datasets? I have the following function:

```
def get_X_of_Y (x, y):
    for person in people:
        if person.position == x and person.company == company.name:
            return person
    else:
        return None
```

Suppose I have thousands of people and hundreds of companies. Is there a faster way to do this then by looping through everyone? I can precompute the objects if there's a way to make things faster.

Comment: `Suppose I have thousands of people and hundreds of companies.` Yes, use a database?

Comment: Agree with mu - use a DB and create an index on the `company` field in table `person`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say

```
data = {
    "people" : {
        "Alice" : {
            "position" : "Manager",
            "company" : "Company1"
        },
        "Bob" : {
            "position" : "CEO",
            "company" : "Company1"
        },
        "Charlie" : {
            "position" : "CEO",
            "company" : "Company2"
        }
    },
    "companies" : [
        { "name" : "Company1" },
        { "name" : "Company2" }
    ]
}
```

Then You could create a list of people, which is basically a flat structure as compared to your nested dict:

```
>>> people = [(key, value["position"], value["company"]) for key, value in data["people"].items()]
[('Charlie', 'Company2', 'CEO'),
 ('Bob', 'Company1', 'CEO'),
 ('Alice', 'Company1', 'Manager')]
```

And also a list of companies, which again does away with structure of dict:

```
>>> companies = [item['name'] for item in data["companies"]]
['Company1', 'Company2']
```

Now querying is pretty simple, use a `filter` method

```
def get_X_of_Y (x, y):
    return filter(lambda item: item[1]==x and item[2]==y, people)
```

And so you can easily search now:

```
>>> get_X_of_Y("CEO", companies[0])
[('Bob', 'CEO', 'Company1')]
```

However, I would still suggest using a database if you really have *thousands of people and hundreds of companies.*

Answer (score 1):

As `mu` says - use a database.

Alternatively you can do what databases do - keep an index on CEOs. So have a dict which looks like:

```
ceos = { "Company1": "Bob", "Company2": "Charlie" }
```

and select from there. You'll have to update that dict every time the list of people changes too.

But for real scenarios?... Just use a database.

---

Edit: regarding the comment "what if I don't know what position I'm looking for" - again do the same thing databases do - create an index from two elements/columns:

```
positions_index = {
    ("Company1", "CEO"): "Bob",
    ("Company1", "Manager"): "Alice",
    ("Company2", "CEO"): "Charlie",
}
```

Comment: But what if I don't know what position I'm looking for - like I might want to retrieve the manager of Company1?